# left invariant derivation

Tags: abstract-algebra, invariant-theory, invariant-subspace

I have defined a derivation in the following way:
Let K be a vector field, A a K-algebra, a derivation $D$ is suhch that
 $D\in Hom_K(A,A)$ and $D(fg)=D(f)g+D(g)f$.
Let here be $A=K[T]$, the ring of polynomials.
 I am having trouble finding an example of a left invariant derivation ( a derivation that commutes with the left traslation of functions)

Comment: I don't think that $K$ is supposed to be a [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field).